# Error while editing data in gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am making an online bug tracking system(BTS) in ASP.NET. I am using Gridview for displaying the records on a web page. It is working properly in some web forms but in some web forms, i am getting error as given below when i click edit event of gridview. Please guide me to solve this error.

## Server Error in '/BTS' Application.

---

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using
`<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>`
 in configuration or
 `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>`
 in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: there is only minor thing u have to write just check my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Just do this --> `EnableEventValidation="false"` like below

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/shirish.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="s.aspx.cs" Inherits="_s" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical error in ASP.NET when request validation fails. The most common scenario is when you are issuing a postback and one of the input controls (usually a TextBox) contains html or javascript code. As the error message states, there's several ways you can bypass this validation:

1. By disabling request validation at the page level which be achieved by setting the `EnableEventValidation` property of the page directive to false. Note that you can do the same site-wide from the `web.config` file
2. By registering the required control for event validation using the [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerforeventvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

If you use the first approach, you will be turning off event validation which means you will be relaxing some of the built-in security features. On the other hand, the second approach is a bit clumsy because it requires to anticipate the values allowed by the control